# Regex rising digits

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to only match rising numbers.
ex: 22335566 66678
but not: 444663 33997777666664

the length of the number is not fixed nor is the starting digit.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to implement this using regex is:

```
^(?=\d)1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$
```

The regex matches:

- 0 or more 1's, followed by,
- 0 or more 2's, followed by,
- 0 or more 3's... and so on.
- `(?=\d)` ensures that there is atleast 1 digit in your string.

Comment: But it will match an empty string also.

Comment: Great, it should work +1

Comment: Oh, didn't think it would be that simple, but my file is for ex: '2233466666begon', how would i add the last word to the regex?

Comment: @user2883717 Add the word before the `$`

Comment: @user2883717 Remember to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark besides the answer.

Comment: the word isn't fixed, any way to make it accept any word?
edit: this doesn't seem to work in bash using the egrep command, but it works in regexpal.com, could there be any compatibility issues?

Comment: I found out why it wasn't working in bash, i forgot to delete all spaces (sorry). Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user2883717 I suggest you to go through some regex tutorial to learn the basics. Matching a word, digit, etc.. are very basic information, which you would probably find in first few pages of any tutorial.